# PHP and RegEx: how to split a string including comma,space,colon to some substring

Tags: php, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string that can either be comma, space or semi-colon delimitted. It could also contain a space or spaces after each delimitter. For example

1. `chr1:22222-333333` or
2. `chr1 22222 333333` or
3. `chr1  22222    333333` or
4. `chr1:22,222-33,333`

Any one of these would produce an array with three values `["chr1","22222","33333"]`, I have tried some method, but it not all complete. especially the fourth case.
Thank you very much for help me.

Comment: Separated by colon, space or semi-colon, I guess you mean

Comment: How do you expect the fourth case to work? Splitting on commas will break `22,222` and `33,333` apart at the comma.

Answer (score 8):

```
$yourString = "chr1:22222-33333"; // for instance

$output = preg_split("/:| |;/", $yourString);
```

This acts as an equivalent of `explode()` but when you want multiple delimiters.

**Explanation of the characters in the preg_split statement:**

`/` acts to enclose the regular expression, as to say `ok, that's happening here`

`|` acts as a `OR` statement, as if to tell `this OR this OR that`

**So that in the end,** `/:| |;/` means `select anything that is ":" or " " or ";"`

If you want to practice or simply understand better the principles of RegEx, you can have a look to this [nice collection of RegEx tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Nice explanation, but please are the `()` necessary? Afaik it is working without them since we're testing single char `|` single char `|` ...

Answer (score 3):

you can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace) with [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = array('chr1:22222-333333', 'chr1 22222 333333', 'chr1 22222 333333', 'chr1:22,222-33,333');
foreach($str as $val){
    var_dump(explode(" ", str_replace(array(',',':','-'), array('',' ', ' '), $val)));
}
```

which pretty much removes all `,` then replaces `:` AND `-` with a space then explodes with spaces as a delimiter.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/tugXFb)

which produces

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "chr1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "22222"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "333333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "chr1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "22222"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "333333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "chr1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "22222"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "333333"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "chr1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "22222"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "33333"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you value conciseness and want to keep things neat, preg_split is the best way to go, in my opinion.

In the following examples, I assume you want your input separated by *commas, spaces or **colons**:*

```
$splitted = preg_split("/[,: ]/", $string);
```

If you want to treat tabs as whitespaces, you can replace the single space character with `\s`, which will match tabs as well:

```
$splitted = preg_split("/[,:\s]/", $string);
```

**Note**: The `\s` will match newlines too, if your input may eventually be a multline string.

Yet, if you don't trust your input (You don't, right?) and think that perhaps subsequent spaces and/or tabs should be ignored and treated as single spaces, you can go with this version:

```
$splitted = preg_split("/,|:|\s/", $string);
```

All the forms above work great provided the input you presented. If you want to play with these a little, [this](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) is a nice place to do so.